# Mixing jquery with razor to create dynamicly added selectlists with selected option

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wanna create selectlists with selected option attribute and i wanna increse the value of "i" each time while im creating another selectlist.

```
var i = -1;
// Hide Section "Loading.gif" On Start 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
    i = i + 1;
    var selects = '@foreach (var selectedone in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Selectlists"]){<tr><td><div id="dive' + i + '"><select name="GroupDetails[' + i + '].cea_id">@foreach(SelectListItem item in (SelectList)ViewData["Suppliers"]){ if(item.Value == selectedone){<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}else{<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>}}</select></div></td></tr>}'
    /* alert(selects); */
    $("mytable").append(selects);
});
```

Just for making it easier to understand the long code up there is this:

```
     /* im getting selected options as numeric like = "2","8","6" */
@foreach (var selectedone in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Selectlists"])
{
<tr>
    <td>
     /* also in here i need to increase the value of "i" each time! but couldnt embed it yet */
        <div id="dive' + i + '">
            <select name="GroupDetails[' + i + '].cea_id">

                @foreach(SelectListItem item in (SelectList)ViewData["Suppliers"])
                { 
     /* if each items value is equals to selected options that i putted. Do the code below.*/
                    if(item.Value == selectedone)
                    {   
     /* i wanna add this option selected attribute but not working this way */
                        <option selected="selected" value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
     /* other options doesnt need to be selected */
                        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: What is happening here? do you get an error or is it just not working? As a side point, you really should consider using ViewModels instead of passing objects through the ViewData dictionary.

Comment: what really happening here is : i do a check if my previously selected items that i call at first "foreach" are matches with the options that i create at second "foreach" i wanna put selected attribute on it. im calling all values by razor and wanna join it to jquery to add these elements dynamicaly. my problem is the selected option attribute is not working at all. and also i would like to know how can i serialize these dynamicly created selectlists while im adding it with razor at the first "foreach".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the options are rendering but none of them are selected? In that case, maybe your equality comparison is failing? Do the values you're comparing implement Equals correctly? If not, then it will only work if they are *exactly* the same instance of the same object.

Comment: u may have a point there im giving same id to each div + same name to each select may be its the problem.

Comment: u were right value was coming as string and some of them got space thats why they were not equals to eachother so i converted them `ToInt32` problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes to see the obvious solution you may have missed ;P.

Comment: By the way, I recommend splitting the code inside "var selects = '...'" into a separate method in a helper class. It will make things a lot cleaner :)

Comment: Razor shouldn't be stopping you from extracting this code into a helper method, but if there's something getting in your way, let me know and I'll see how I can help.